# connection error while doing remote access to linux virtual machine from windows with AZURE

Tags: linux, azure, deployment, virtual-machine

I have deployed the virtual machine on azure and used Putty software to follow all the steps required for remote access.
I referred the following link  -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMeprVU0yIw&t=509s
 but after remote access the following error pop ups.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOHwl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you following the documentation for doing this directly from Ubuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI

The video you provide is 2 years old and the way that Azure evolves so quickly it is likely no longer valid.